# Dark Mode in html,css,js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

so I have the following code:

```js
let darkMode = false;
const DOMDarkMode = document.querySelector(".dark");
const DOMLightMode = document.querySelector(".light");

function toggle(x, y) {
    // Calculating circle size to fill a background
    bubbleSize = Math.max(
        // Distances calculating: to the click point..
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)), // ..from left-top point
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(innerWidth - x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)), // ..from right-top point
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(innerHeight - y, 2)), // ..from bottom-left point
        Math.sqrt(Math.pow(innerWidth - x, 2) + Math.pow(innerHeight - y, 2)), // ..from bottom-right point
    );
    
    if (darkMode) {
        darkMode = false;
        DOMLightMode.style.setProperty("--x", x + "px");
        DOMLightMode.style.setProperty("--y", y + "px");
        DOMLightMode.style.setProperty("--size-to-fill", bubbleSize + "px");
        
        DOMLightMode.classList.add("active");
        DOMDarkMode.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
        darkMode = true;
        DOMDarkMode.style.setProperty("--x", x + "px");
        DOMDarkMode.style.setProperty("--y", y + "px");
        DOMDarkMode.style.setProperty("--size-to-fill", bubbleSize + "px");
        
        DOMDarkMode.classList.add("active");
        DOMLightMode.classList.remove("active");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("click", e=>{
    toggle(e.x, e.y)
});

// IFRAME EFFECT

let iframe = true;
let tick = false;
let end = false;

setTimeout(()=>{ tick = true; }, 500);
setTimeout(()=>{ tick = true; }, 1500);
setTimeout(()=>{ end = true; }, 2100);

document.addEventListener("mouseover", e=>{ iframe = false; });

effects = setInterval(()=>{
    if (!iframe)
        end = true;
    if (tick == true) {
        tick = false;
        toggle(0, 0);
    }
    if (end) {
        darkMode = false;
        DOMLightMode.classList.remove("active");
        DOMDarkMode.classList.remove("active");
        clearInterval(effects);
    }
}, 0);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    user-select: none;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Yusei Magic', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: .4em;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
}
.mode {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box {
    margin: 2em;
}
.active {
    z-index: 2;
    animation: show .6s ease;
}

@keyframes show {
    from {
        clip-path: circle(0 at var(--x) var(--y));
    }
    to {
        clip-path: circle(var(--size-to-fill) at var(--x) var(--y));
    }
}

.light {
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
}
.dark {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
    <div class="dark mode">
    </div>
    <div class="light mode">
    </div>
</div>
```

If you click anywhere, it toggles from dark mode to light mode and vice-versa. My question is where should I include the `html` of the above code in my website so it applies to the whole website, because right now, whenever I click somewhere, only my homepage toggles from dark mode to light mode and vice-versa. But how would I make it so that the above code works for the whole website, and wherever in my website I click, the whole website switches from dark mode to light mode and vice-versa.

I tried including the code at the top of my website's `index.html` after the `head` section but it still does not work. Any suggestions?
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go is to try cookies! WHen you load a page it is normal it does not retain information form the last one. The best way to go around it is to save a cookie with javascript and load that cookie each time you load a page!